# Let T be a linear transformation. Find the standard matrix of T

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let T be a linear transformation given by $T(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (-4x_2 - 4x_3, -2x_1 + 6x_2 + 2x_3, -x_1 - 2x_3, 4x_2 + 4x_3)$. Find the standard matrix of T.

I assumed the answer is

$$
 \pmatrix{0&-4&-4\\-2&6&2\\-1&0&-2\\0&4&4} 
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: This looks right.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is perfect! You have $T(1,0,0)$ in the first column (with respect to the standard basis), $T(0,1,0)$ in the second one and $T(0,0,1)$ in the last one.

Now you can be more "self-confident" when you compute standard matrices.

Comment: How would you know if it is one-to-one and whether it maps to $R^3 onto R^4$?

Comment: Do you know the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)? You always have that the rank of $T : V \to W$ is smaller than the dimension of the space $V$ which is 3 is this case. So $T$ can't be onto (and then it is not one-to-one either).